# Adding users to a Form-based authentication site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio-2013, spuser

I'm using SharePoint **Foundation** 2013. I have created an Extranet where Active Directory and Form based users could log in (multi mode). I need to add users to this site via a windows service. My question is of two parts.

1. By default there is a Reader group created when the site is created. How can I add a user to this default group? (Rather than hard coding group name)
2. Is there a recommended approach to add Form based users to the site? (I am storing the form based users in a SQL DB table.)

Comment: do you want progmatically or manully?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE programatically

Answer (score -1):

see this :
(storing the form based users in a SQL DB table)
http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2013/09/20/configuring-sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-with-sqlmembershipprovider.aspx

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)